# Email Publisher attributes behave differently

Tags: visualforce, email

We have an Email Publisher in the service console page with a custom template in the body.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="FeedEmailExtn"  >
  <!--<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery)}"  />-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var cid = '{!case.id}';
    function afterSendingEmail()
    {
        alert('test alert');
        FeedEmailExtn.afterSendingEmail(cid, function(result, event){
            if(event.status) {
                window.top.location='/console';
            }
        });
    }
  </script>
  <apex:emailPublisher entityId="{!case.id}" 
      fromVisibility="hidden"
      subjectVisibility="editable" 
      toVisibility="editableWithLookup"
      toAddresses="{!case.contact.email}"
      autoCollapseBody="false"
      expandableHeader="false"
      bccVisibility="hidden"
      ccVisibility="editableWithLookup"
      enableQuickText="true"
      emailBodyFormat="textAndHTML"
      rendered="{!EmailDisplay}"
      onSubmitSuccess="afterSendingEmail();"
      width="100%"
      verticalResize="true"
       />
</apex:page>
```

This is the Controller Extensions Code

```
global class FeedEmailExtn{

    private Case cas;

    public FeedEmailExtn(ApexPages.StandardController std)
    {
        this.cas = (Case) std.getRecord();
        this.cas = [SELECT Id, ContactId FROM Case WHERE Id=:cas.Id];
    }

    public boolean getEmailDisplay()
    {
        return ((!(getContactInfo())));
    }

    public boolean getContactInfo()
    {
        return (cas.ContactId == null);
    }
    @RemoteAction
    global static string afterSendingEmail(String cid)
    {
        AnswerBox.SetAnsBox(cid, false);
        return 'AfterSendingEmail is done for ' + cid;
    }
}
```

Whenever we send an email, the Javascript in OnSubmitSuccess attribute is invoked and the page is reloaded. Suddenly it stopped functioning. The template in the body disappears and the page does not reload. But when I called this Javascript function in OnSubmitFailure attribute by adding this attribute,

```
onSubmitFailure="afterSendingEmail();"
```

the email is sent and the Javascript is invoked and the page is reloaded. I'm wondering how can an email be sent successfully and a Javascript function in the OnSumitFailure attribute can be invoked. Any idea of why this is happening. Thanks.

Comment: I see from your code above that you're actually using jQuery `<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery)}"  />` not JavaScript. I suggest you take a look at your include script for any issues, along with the available jQuery event handlers, then update your jQuery code accordingly.

Comment: Hey @crmprogdev. I've removed the jquery script and added the type as "text/javascript" to the script tag. <script type="text/javascript"> But still the issue continues.

Comment: The `jQuery` function that's problematic is being called from your Case controller extension `FeedEmailExtn` as specified in this line: `<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="FeedEmailExtn">`. You can't arbitrarily change the script type to JS. The code you've posted doesn't look like jQuery to me. If it were, I'd expect each line to start with a $ sign. Perhaps posting your controller code might help someone troubleshoot your problem since the function being called is from the extension. The jQuery callout is to a static resource that may only be a library, but could be more.

Comment: @crmprogdev I've posted the controller code. I've commented out the include script. No jquery since I've used the Javascript remoting in vf page to call the method in the controller.

Comment: First, I know next to nothing about JS remoting. That said, it would appear to me that the problem is related to `AnswerBox.SetAnsBox(cid, false);` which appears to be part of your remoted code. I suggest you track down where that function/controller/code is located and find out why its not responding as it did prior to the start of your problem.

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to. Even I was thinking the same but then I included an ALERT in the Javascript to know whether the function is being called or not. Once the email is sent, there is no alert message which means the Javascript function is not invoked. So I thought there is a problem in this visualforce page. P.S. But the same javascript function is called when I call in the OnSubmitFailure.